# How to scale an image on another image responsively

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

I need to put an image of an icon ( the play button ) over a thumbnail of a video, but it should stay in the middle (vertically and horizontally) regardless of the width of the windows or device and also scale according to the windwos width . My image is scaling well according to the window but my icon is not. I found many solutions, but they all had defined height and width in px, which i do not want. I want my icon to have a dynamic width and height according to the windows width.

here is my css

```
.video-section .video-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 36%;
    left: 43.8%;
}
.video-section .bg-img {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Then just use percentage width/height for the icon to make it responsive to its parent container, see my updated answer.

Comment: I cant use percentage width/height to make icon responsive as the icon is an absolute image, so 100% is the max width of the image meaning it has nothing to do with the browser width, but i want my image to scale according to browser width..

Comment: Can you demonstrate this in a jsFiddle? Have you thought about using viewport units instead of percentages? try `vh` or `vw`

Comment: Tried that, but if i use something like width: calc( 50% + 2vw); it messes with the middle alignment :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can do it like this:

```css
.video-section .bg-img {
  position: relative;
  background: lightblue;
  height: 300px;
  width: 50%;
}

.video-section .video-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-section">
  <div class="bg-img">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" alt="" class="video-icon">
  </div>
</div>
```

no need for transform.

**Edit:** user percentage width/height to make icon responsive.

Comment: @GauravAggarwal less code and does not require vendor prefixes - anyway, it's not critical. use whatever you like!

Comment: This method is not user friendly as there are so many cases where we cant decide height and width and with prefix transform is supported by all browsers

Comment: I cant use percentage width/height to make icon responsive as the icon is an absolute image, so 100% is the max width of the image meaning it has nothing to do with the browser width, but i want my image to scale according to browser width..

Answer (score 0):

Scale it like this

```
.video-section .video-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Above `transform` property will work in all browsers only if you add prefix in it otherwise it may not work with all browsers.

Code should be like this

```
.video-section .video-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -moz-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -o-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Comment: No, you dont understand my image does come in the middle always, but the image does not SCALE in height and width...i need it to reduce in height and width automatically...

Comment: please ask questions clearly...in your question u mentioned that you icon is not aligned but image is aligned..